# neomutt+lieer: how to make deletion in neomutt sync properly to GMail?

Tags: email, gmail, notmuch, neomutt

I've recently migrated from mutt to neomutt, and have at the same time been moving from accessing my mailboxes live through IMAP to working with local frequently-synced copies, with a notmuch database. I have both an Outlook (work) address and a Gmail (personal) address. The outlook mail I'm syncing with davmail and OfflineIMAP, and AFAICT it's working well. It's the GMail that's giving me grief; I'm syncing it with lieer which seems to for the most part do a good job, but I'm having a really difficult time with handling the process for message deletion. I can't find anyone else with this specific problem, so I'm guessing the answer is something stupidly simple I'm doing wrong.

I'm basically trying to follow more-or-less the workflow described [here](https://www.jevy.org/articles/neomutt-lieer-notmuch/), although I'm not even trying to use lieer to send mail. The issue AFACT is that neomutt seems to follow one of a few behaviors with regard to what "deleting" a message means, and none of them seem to play quite right with the kind of thing lieeer wants to see to ensure a message is trashed cloudside. Here are the prospects I've looked at:

- `maildir_trash` set to "no", `trash` unset. AFAICT, this setting makes neomutt unlink (as in, remove the associated file in the appropriate Maildirs) the message. Since lieer won't/can't push deletions (which is probably a good thing), that doesn't remove the messages cloudside on sync.
- `maildir_trash` set to "no", `trash` set. This is what I used to do, because IMAP connection to GMail provided a [Trash] folder. lieer seems to bring everything in with one monolithic maildir folder (called "mail", and within the lieer working directory), so unless there's a clever way to do this so that trash is a tag rather than a directory, it still doesn't seem to do what I want; changing the path to a message file seems like it would resemble a deletion to lieer, since it would take it out of the lieer sync path.
- `maildir_trash` set to "yes". This seemed really pretty promising, because it seemed like it would set a flag rather than relocate the file, leaving it in the right directory but flagged as trash. Unfortunately, that flag never seems to make it to notmuch (this is apparently [by design](https://git.notmuchmail.org/git/notmuch/commit/2c262042ac174d7bc96d6035ab9c88bd0abe7f35)) and thus never makes it to lieer. I could add another layer of byzantine automation to translate the flag myself, but I assume if that were necessary someone else would have talked about it.

A nonzero number of other people use lieer, notmuch, and neomutt, and nothing I've searched on suggests others have this problem, which suggests I've somehow broken something configured correctly by default? I include below an anonymized version of my `.notmuch-config` and most of my `.neomuttrc` (there's a lot of code to color various specific message patterns which I've elided, as it's probably not relevant):

```
[database]
path=/home/username/Private/.mail

[user]
primary_email=username@gmail.com
other_email=username@work.edu

[new]
tags=new
ignore=/.*[.](json|lock|bak)$/

[search]

[maildir]
synchronize_flags=true

[query]
workmail=folder:account.work/INBOX
gmail=folder:/account.gmail/ AND tag:inbox AND NOT tag:trash
```

```
virtual-mailboxes work "notmuch://?query=query:workmail"
virtual-mailboxes gmail "notmuch://?query=query:gmail"
virtual-mailboxes allmail "notmuch://?query=query:workmail OR query:gmail"

send2-hook '~f gmail.com' "source ~/.mutt/accounts/muttrc.gmail"
send2-hook '~f work.edu' "source ~/.mutt/accounts/muttrc.work"

reply-hook '~C work.edu' "source ~/.mutt/accounts/muttrc.work"
reply-hook '~C username.*@gmail.com' "source ~/.mutt/accounts/muttrc.gmail"

message-hook '!(~g|~G) ~b"^-----BEGIN\ PGP\ (SIGNED\ )?MESSAGE"' "exec check-traditional-pgp"

unignore date

alternates '^username'

source "~/.mutt_aliases"

set abort_noattach=ask-no
set abort_noattach_regex = "\\<attach(|ed|ments?)\\>"
set abort_unmodified=ask-yes
set alias_file="~/.mutt_aliases"
set allow_ansi=yes
set arrow_cursor=yes
set askbcc=yes
set askcc=yes
set beep=no
set beep_new=yes
set certificate_file="~/.mutt_certs"
set confirm_append=no
set copy=yes
set crypt_auto_sign=yes
set edit_headers=yes
set editor="emacs -nw"
set folder="~/.mail"
set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set history=20
set implicit_autoview=yes
set keep_flagged=yes
set mailcap_path="~/.mailcap"
set maildir_trash=yes
set mbox_type="Maildir"
set message_cachedir=~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set mime_forward=ask-no
set move=no
set nm_default_uri  = "notmuch:///home/username/.mail"
set pager_stop=yes
set pgp_clear_sign_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --output - %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --armor --textmode --clearsign %?a?-u %a? %f"
set pgp_decode_command="gpg --status-fd=2 %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --no-verbose --quiet --batch --output - %f"
set pgp_decrypt_command="gpg --status-fd=2 %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --no-verbose --quiet --batch --output - %f"
set pgp_encrypt_only_command="/usr/lib/mutt/pgpewrap gpg --batch --quiet --no-verbose --output - --encrypt --textmode --armor --always-trust -- -r %r -- %f"
set pgp_sign_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --output - %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --armor --detach-sign --textmode %?a?-u %a? %f"
set pgp_encrypt_sign_command="/usr/lib/mutt/pgpewrap gpg %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --batch --quiet --no-verbose --textmode --output - --encrypt --sign %?a?-u %a? --armor --always-trust -- -r %r -- %f"
set pgp_export_command="gpg --no-verbose --export --armor %r"
set pgp_good_sign="^\\[GNUPG:\\] GOODSIG"
set pgp_import_command="gpg --no-verbose --import %f"
set pgp_list_pubring_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --with-colons --list-keys %r" 
set pgp_list_secring_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --with-colons --list-secret-keys %r" 
set pgp_sign_as="0xXXXXXXXX"
set pgp_timeout=1800
set pgp_verify_command="gpg --status-fd=2 --no-verbose --quiet --batch --output - --verify %s %f"
set pgp_verify_key_command="gpg --verbose --batch --fingerprint --check-sigs %r"
set print_command="enscript -Pkether/2 --margins=:::72 --header='Page $% of $='
set realname = "My Real Name"
set record="+sent-mail"
set signature="$HOME/.signatures/sign|"
set sort = threads
set sort_aux = last-date-received
set spool_file = allmail
set text_flowed=yes
```

Many thanks to anyone who can help!